# What can be skipped during installation?

Tags: 13.10, system-installation

During installation of Ubuntu I clicked the skip button like a maniac, because I had nothing better to do. Assuming that I skipped everything that can be skipped. What did I skip?

Answer (score 3):

The updates , third party software such as mp3 encoding...Logging in with a ubuntu account
I think that's all.

You can get the updates from update manager , then install restricted extras from the software center for multimedia codes and stuff. and you can log in with a ubuntu account on the software center if you want

Comment: If you would list what I have to do to unskip what I skipped I would accept your answer. You might be skipping because of a bad internet connection and it would be useful to have a script (or at least clear instructions) to perform the skipped steps after the connection problems have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can unchecked installing updates and third-party software , so installation time will be reduced , but its highly recommended to download updates , after installation you could  download them .